# JS count down timer

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple JS countdown timer. The timer-- is not working.

```js
function setTimer() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value);
  var timer = Math.floor(x * 60);
  var mins = Math.floor(timer / 60);
  var secs = Math.floor(timer % 60);
  var text =
    document.getElementById("output");
  text.innerHTML = mins + " : " +
    secs;
  timer--;
  setTimeout('setTimer()', 1000);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="btn" onClick="setTimer()"> Start </button>
```

The timer is not reducing. Can you please help?

Comment: You don't have a function called `setTimer`.

Comment: Sorry, first time posting a question, so made a mistake. I do have a function.

Comment: You don't have an `output` element. Basic debugging would have solved this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `timer` variable is not changing because it is taking the value again from the input. I have simplified your code below

```
<html>
    <script>
        var timer;
        function setTimer() {
            var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value);
            timer = Math.floor(x * 60);

            handleTimer(timer);
        }

        function handleTimer(timer) {
            var mins = Math.floor(timer / 60);
            var secs = Math.floor(timer % 60);
            document.getElementById("output").value = mins + " : " + secs;
            timer--;
            setTimeout(function () {
                handleTimer(timer);
            }, 1000);
        }
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="input" />
    <input type="text" id="output" placeholder="output" />
    <button id="btn" onClick="setTimer()">Start</button>
</html>
```